# Puts an array vertically and left justified

Tags: ruby, arrays

This is a follow up to one of my previous questions. When I run this program, the arrays are shown as ["1", "2", "3] etc.

This is my code:

```
#Table of Contents using an array
linewidth = 50
title = "Table of Consents"

#Needs chapters inputted
chapters = Array.new

puts "Please input chapter names."

while (input = gets.chomp) != ""
  break if input.chomp.empty?
  chapters << input
end

#Needs corresponding page numbers inputted
pagenumbers = Array.new

puts "Please input corresponding page numbers."

while (pagenum = gets.chomp) != ""
  break if pagenum.chomp.empty?
  pagenumbers << pagenum
end

leftside = chapters.to_s
rightside = "Pg. " + pagenumbers.to_s

puts title.center(50)
puts leftside.ljust(30) + rightside.rjust(30)
```

When I run it, it looks like this.

> ```
> MBP-ERDOS:Programs chriserdos$ ruby TOCarray.rb
> Please input chapter names.
> born 
> dead
> live
>
> Please input corresponding page numbers.
> 1
> 43
> 99
>
>                 Table of Consents                 
> ["born ", "dead", "live"]              Pg. ["1", "43", "99"]
> ```

I'd like for the array to be printed like this:

born
dead
live

with the corresponding page numbers right justified on the same line.

New to Ruby, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of all the code after your while loop and put this instead:

```
data = chapter.zip(pagenumbers)

puts title.center(50)

data.each do |left, right|
  puts left.ljust(30) + right.rjust(30)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just the strict answer to your question is:

```
puts title.center(50)
leftside.each_with_index { |x, i| puts "#{x.ljust(30)}#{rightside[i].rjust(30)}" }
```

But there is more methods to do it. Please take time to do some Ruby course or read a book, it is worth to do it.